# Units in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm considering the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, where $\omega=\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}=e^{i \pi/3}$.
I'm trying to prove that $a+b\omega \in \mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ is invertible if and only if $|a+b\omega|=1$.
Here I'm defining $| \cdot |$ to be the usual complex modulus $\sqrt{(a+b\omega)(a+b\overline{\omega})}$.
Any tips as to how to approach this proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Use $N(z)=|z|^2= z \bar z$. Then $z \in \mathbb Z[\omega] \implies N(z) \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: So if $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, then $\alpha\beta=1$. We can then say that $1=|1|=|\alpha\beta|=|\alpha||\beta|$. Since $| \cdot |$ is always positive and $|\alpha|,|\beta|$ must be integers, then we conclude that $|\alpha|=1$?

Comment: @bzoll213, yes, exactly.